# Accessing Couchbase server from OSX

Tags: macos, vagrant, couchbase, osx-elcapitan

I have configured Couchbase Server on Vagrant VM but not able access it.
 Used this [blogpost](http://goo.gl/QpuFlQ) to setup Vagrantfile and puppet file. `vagrant up` command shows

```
notice: Finished catalog run in -65.00 seconds
```

for each node with no error.

I tried accessing both `http://192.168.56.101` and `http://192.168.56.101:8091` but none worked.

Is there a network setting I am missing? Because all 4 VMs looks healthy.

Comment: can you ssh into the VM and check if couchbase is installed and running ?

Comment: note that the port used to show the couchbase webconsole is `8091`, did you try `http://192.168.56.101:8091`?

Answer (score 0):

I normally SSH into one of the nodes - `vagrant ssh node` - and see what IP address it's ended up with - `ifconfig`, then connect to port 8091 of that IP.

BTW you didn't specify which Vagrant scripts  you are using, but there's an [unofficial Couchbase repo](https://github.com/couchbaselabs/vagrants) which has pretty much all the different Couchbase versions available.